# Excel hide textArea

Tags: excel

What I would like to do is that when I click on a specific excel text area it will hide it immediately.

I tried this =>

```
Sub ZoneTexte2_Cliquer()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes("ZoneTexte2").Visible = False
End Sub
```

But I don't know too much things in VBA scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've assigned the macro using the "Assign Macro" menu item for the shape then your code is almost correct.

Try `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Visible = False`

Which can be used as a generic handler for all shape click events, assuming you assign it to all your shapes first.

If you want to use their names directly, you might need to use the following to get their correct name for later use.

`msgbox Prompt:=ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name`

If you click on a shape with that code in the macro it will show a message box containing its proper name, for text area shapes it is usually "Text Box N" (spaces and capitalization are important)

Answer (score 1):

Some vba...

```
Public OrigColumn As Integer
Public OrigRow   As Integer
Public OrigValue As String
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If OrigColumn = 0 And OrigRow = 0 And OrigValue = "" Then
        ' first time usage, there is no history selection...
    Else
        ' show the original value when enter out the cell
        Cells(OrigRow, OrigColumn).Value = OrigValue
    End If

    OrigColumn = Target.Column
    OrigRow = Target.Row
    OrigValue = Target.Value

    Target.Value = Null
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: this is a way to hide the values in the cell itself, I thought Meds was looking for hidding values, but it is about shapes.